# Java, Eclipse, Ant: How to create custom class generator dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, class, ant

I want to create custom dialog for creating classes inside eclipse.

I want this dialog to have name field, for method name, and parameters field for method parameters. With eclipse auto complete option for know types.

Then I will create a package and inside this package I will create a class that implements interface from the given parameters.

Where do I start? Is there any tutorials that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The best will be to create Eclipse plugin so the first thing you should do is to read something about Eclipse RPC. [This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) tutorial should help you to start with it.